# How can I add custom partitioner in Kafka Connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have connected MongoDB Atlas with my Kafka using MongoDB source connector. Now I want to store message to a specific partition in my topic by using some hash function.

I have looked in the documentation of confluent about adding a custom partitioner, but I found nothing.

Comment: do you need help in creating a partitioner or defining one?

Answer (score 1):

Source Connectors are just producers. Producers control partitioning.

In Connect, you can set the partitioner producer property by

```
producer.override.partitioner.class=your.custom.Partitioner
```

After you upload a JAR to the Connect worker classpath (which is not possible in managed Confluent Cloud connectors)